# Java 8 : Lambda Function and Generic Wildcards

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have the following class

```
class Book implement Borrowable  {
    @Override
    public String toString(Function<? extends Borrowable
                            , String> format) {
          return format.apply(this);    
    }
}
```

This gives me an error that i cannot use "apply" on this(Book object).

My current formatter is

```
 Function<Book, String> REGULAR_FORMAT = book -> "name='" + book.name + '\'' +
        ", author='" + book.author + '\'' +
        ", year=" + book.year;
```

I don't want to make the lambda function of the type

```
Function<Borrowable, String>
```

as I would lose access to the members of Book not exposed by Borrowable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `Function<? extends Borrowable, String>` type means function that able to accept *some* type which extends `Borrowable`. It does not mean that it accepts `Book`. Probably the best solution is to introduce the generic parameter for `Borrowable`:

```
public interface Borrowable<T> {
    public String toString(Function<? super T, String> format);
}
```

And specify it in `Book`:

```
public class Book implements Borrowable<Book> {
    @Override
    public String toString(Function<? super Book, String> format) {
        return format.apply(this);
    }
}
```

It's similar to how the `Comparable` interface works.

Comment: It worked. Even though I don't understand how your solution. A link or little more insights would be greatly helpful

Comment: With `String toString(Function<? extends Borrowable, String> format);` the issue is that you can supply the parameter with an object of type `Function<Movie, String>`, where `Movie` extends `Borrowable`. In that case it's not safe to call `format.apply(this)` on the Function, because `this` is a `Book`, not a `Movie`.
`? super Book` means that the function can have a parameter of type Book, or one of Book's super types (here `Borrowable<Book>` and `Object`). Therefore it would be safe to call `format.apply(this)`, because `this` is a Book, which is a `Borrowable<Book>`, which is an `Object`.

Answer (score 5):

You might be looking for `Function<? super Book, String>`.

A `Function<Book, String>` is a valid `Function<? extends Borrowable, String>`, but so is a `Function<DVD, String>`. Your method (`toString`) might be called with a `Function<DVD, String>`, which you can't pass `this` to because `this` isn't a `DVD`!

Change the argument type to `Function<? super Book, String>`, perhaps.

Comment: note that it's overridden, so it's actually defined in the `Borrowable` interface.

Comment: @TagirValeev It should work, since `Function<? super Borrowable, String>` is a subtype of `Function<? super Book, String>` (and yes, I got that the right way around, I think)

Comment: It does not work. You cannot override method in subtype specifying different argument types even though they're compatible. Only return type and declared exceptions can be narrowed.

Comment: @TagirValeev I thought it also allowed widening parameters. Apparently not.

Comment: @immibis narrowing would make sense. (not allowed either)

Comment: @bayou.io Narrowing would **not** make sense for parameters. Widening would. Consider `class A {void go(Number n);} class B extends A {@Override void go(Integer n);} class C {{A a = new B(); a.go(5.2);}}`